# C/C++ casting different with function versus expression?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

double metersToFeet(double meters)
{
    return meters / 0.3048;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%u\n", (unsigned char)(char)(45.72 / 0.3048));
    printf("%u\n", (unsigned char)(char)metersToFeet(45.72));
    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs (on both GCC and Clang):

```
127
150
```

Why am I getting two different numbers?

Comment: In the first case the compiler pre-calculates the value and decides that the result (150) is larger than will fit into a char, so truncates that to 127.  In the second case the value is not pre-calculated, so the runtime does whatever the runtime will do with an erroneous cast.

Comment: Yes, this behaviour is called *saturation* but isn't required or to be relied upon. Relying upon undefined behaviour is like putting a blindfold on when you cross the road.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Having such a fitting user name, why didn't you use the chances it provides in this context (like ending the comment with *"Don't mess with"* or something similar)? Keep in mind that comments are to be read by humans and thus subject to artistic expression!

Comment: @ChristianRau Suppose I change my username to "Acute Lymphatic Leukemia"..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real answer (150) exceeds the range of a `char` (on a normal system) if it's signed.  This conversion invokes **undefined behaviour**; the compiler is free to do whatever it likes.

From the C99 standard, 6.3.1.4:

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool,
>   the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of
>   the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: And which compiler on earth would perform saturation on literal-overflow while doing nothing on variable-overflow. But ok, UB is UB.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Well the latter requires runtime overhead.

Comment: The *"latter"*, you mean *"doing nothing"*? Well ok, might be true when doing the whole conversion with SSE, whose integer narrowing conversions are by nature more targeted for saturation.

Comment: @ChristianRau: ah sorry, I meant doing saturation at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

`45.72 / 0.3048` is `150`.

Type `char` on your platform is apparently a 8-but signed type. `150` is out of range for that type. This means that the behavior is undefined. The rest follows.

For example, I'm getting `127 127` in GCC through ideone.com, and `150 150` in MSVC. You got `127 150`, which is amusing, but not surprising.